# UIPickerview with FormatterDecimalStyle

Tags: ios, uipickerview, formatter

In a `UIPickerView`, how can you display numbers so that every thousand there is a comma?

Can you apply the `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle` to it? If so how do you correctly code for it?

Comment: Post you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumber *bigNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:20000];
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
numFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

NSLog(@"Not formatted: %@", bigNum);
NSLog(@"Formatted: %@", [numFormatter stringFromNumber:bigNum]);
```

Would return:

```
Not formatted: 20000
Formatted: 20,000
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would you apply it in the context of a UIPickerView component? The component is a string which contains numbers from 250,000 to 5,000,000. How to get the picker to show the commas is my question? thank you

Comment: Yes, I answered the question. If you're unable to take the provided solution and apply it to the `UIPickerView` I would recommend looking for a tutorial on how to set one up.